RuleException : \rules/build electricity.smk
I am trying PyPSA-EUR tutorial Electrycity-Only.
After running the only code:
snakemake results/test-elec/networks/base_s_6_elec_lcopt_.nc --configfile config/test/config.electricity.yaml

I got a rule exception:
RuleException:
CalledProcessError in file E:\PyPSA\pypsa-eur\rules/build_electricity.smk, line 28:Command 'E:/Anaconda/envs/pypsa-eur/python.exe "E:\PyPSA\pypsa-eur .snakemake\scriptsitmp 0ckuen5.build_electricity_demand.py"" returned non-zero exit status 1.[Mon Dec 2 21:16:09 2024]
Error in rule build electricity demand:
jobid: 19
input: data/electricity_demand_raw.csv, data/load_synthetic_raw.csvoutput: resources/test/electricity demand.csvlog: logs/test/build_electricity_demand.log (check log file(s) for error details)conda-env: E:\PyPSA\pypsa-eur.snakemake\conda\59121625383c6740896e1ce4ceee23ff

And when I look into the log file "build_electricity_demand.log" it says:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\PyPSA\pypsa-eur\.snakemake\scripts\tmpmdsfe0c7.build_electricity_demand.py", line 319, in <module>
    synthetic_load = synthetic_load.loc[snapshots, countries]
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pypsa-eur\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1184, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pypsa-eur\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1375, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._multi_take(tup)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pypsa-eur\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1327, in _multi_take
    axis: self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pypsa-eur\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1558, in _get_listlike_indexer
    keyarr, indexer = ax._get_indexer_strict(key, axis_name)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pypsa-eur\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 6200, in _get_indexer_strict
    self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pypsa-eur\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 6249, in _raise_if_missing
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex(['2013-03-01 00:00:00', '2013-03-01 01:00:00',\n               '2013-03-01 02:00:00', '2013-03-01 03:00:00',\n               '2013-03-01 04:00:00', '2013-03-01 05:00:00',\n               '2013-03-01 06:00:00', '2013-03-01 07:00:00',\n               '2013-03-01 08:00:00', '2013-03-01 09:00:00',\n               ...\n               '2013-03-07 14:00:00', '2013-03-07 15:00:00',\n               '2013-03-07 16:00:00', '2013-03-07 17:00:00',\n               '2013-03-07 18:00:00', '2013-03-07 19:00:00',\n               '2013-03-07 20:00:00', '2013-03-07 21:00:00',\n               '2013-03-07 22:00:00', '2013-03-07 23:00:00'],\n              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=168, freq='h')] are in the [index]"


Does anybody know what casued the error? And how to fix it?
I tried to debug it, thinking the problem may lie in the file retrive.smk, line 180 : rule retrieve_synthetic_electricity_demand, where the code generated a wrong load_synthetic_raw.csv file who didn't have the expected timesteps.
